Data can not be synchronized from production env of local machine (wsl) to render.com. How to solve this PSQL data persistence issue?
I have deployed rails api on render using psql.Tables of procuction env(vsCode-WSL) found also in render.com database, but data input through vsCode (WSL)cannot be found in render database. However, when I test with postman GET request it sends a blank array with 200 ok status. Data can be added from POST request of postman and from frontend form & then we can find the data with GET request both from frontend app and postman.
Note that, 'RAILS_ENV=production rails dbconsole' is showing data perfectly in my WSL-vsCode.
No error/warning was found in render log.
I'm stuck here for a week. So, I need your help.
I choose the render: blueprint option.  I used render generate render.yaml file in my app.
Exported from Render on 2024-10-06T15:18:47Z
databases:

name: medic-api
databaseName: postgres_wjjk
user: postgres_wjjk_user
plan: free
region: oregon
ipAllowList: []
postgresMajorVersion: "16"
services:
type: web
name: rails
runtime: ruby
repo: https://github.com/HossainAraf/medic-api
branch: handle-request
plan: free
envVars:

key: RAILS_MASTER_KEY
sync: false
key: DATABASE_URL
fromDatabase:
name: medic-api
property: connectionString
region: oregon
buildCommand: ./bin/render-build.sh
startCommand: bundle exec rails server
version: "1"



// database.yml file :
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
development:
<<: *default
database: medic-api_development
test:
<<: *default
database: medic-api_test
production:
<<: *default
url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
database: medic-api
password: <%= ENV["MEDIC_API_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
// render-build.sh file:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exit on error
set -o errexit
bundle install
bundle exec rails db:migrate
bin/rails db:migrate
///////
I created different databases. I created new rails app -api with postgresql. I removed old blueprint and create new blueprints in render.com. Then I created database and web-services manually. After all of these attempts I failed to sycronize data from my local machine to render psql-database.
